Is ThreadX mit NetX module a POSIX OS?
Lots of open source library are based on POSIX API, like open62541for OPC UA.
Now I'm working with RTOS Eclipse ThreadX with NetX as TCP/IP module, does anyone know, whether ThreadX has a POSIX like layer. If so, where could I find it?
How to port open62541 into Eclipse ThreadX?

As far as I know, open62541 does not support NetX by default. But the code architecture allows to implement a custom network layer. See the arch folder in the sources for this: https://github.com/open62541/open62541/tree/6fb959189261e072032f1c12ae91940394f60ca7/arch
